# PHP exec commands running unintentionally as root

Tags: php, linux, apache

I am very confused and concerned about the user ownership of commands run via the PHP "exec" statement. I am running PHP 5.5/Apache 2.2/CENTOS 6 in a cPanel/WHM environment with the DSO/mod_ruid handler.

In a test, I have the following php script:

```
<?php
  echo 'whoami: ',exec('whoami'),'<br />';
  echo 'user: ',exec('echo ${USER}'),'<br />';
  echo 'home: ',exec('echo ${HOME}'),'<br />';
?>
```

When I run the script through my browser, I see these results:

```
whoami: cuser
user: root
home: /root
```

where *cuser* is my system's cPanel ID and the user ID in the suPHP, mod_ruid, and mpm-itk directives in my domain's virtual host httpd.conf configuration.

Furthermore, my httpd.conf file assigns "nobody" as the User and Group and, indeed, my httpd processes (as returned from the "ps -ef | grep httpd") are owned by "nobody".

My question is why the exec commands return different results for the "whoami" and "echo ${USER}" commands and whether there is a security risk because of an error in my Apache configuration. Optimally, I'd like my exec commands to run as the *cuser* user. Can I make that happen?

Thank you very much for any information you can provide.

Comment: I discovered that although the USER and HOME directory point to root in a bash script run through PHP exec, the privileges and context are actually that of the suPHP/cPanel ID and the exec command doesn't have root privileges. That's a good thing. But the HOME variable points to /root and that's a problem. I need to run libreoffice headless via an exec command and libreoffice needs access to the current home directory, which unfortunately is pointing to root. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Figured it out: I can override the HOME directory by entering my exec command as follows:   exec('HOME=/home/cuser sh script.sh'). Sorry for having opened the question.

Comment: Could be useful information for someone with the same problem. Be sure to provide the above solution as an Answer to this question, and mark it answered.

Answer (score 0):

Per Gralgrathor's comment, here is my work-around:

I can override the HOME directory by entering my exec command as follows: exec('HOME=/home/cuser sh script.sh'). Note though that ${USER} in script.sh still points to ROOT, so beware!